# We have age columns and in that we have single values or 15+ values we need to have single value or 15+

Tags: sql

If source value is 3 or 4 then target value is 3 or 4. If source having any minus value then -1 and if source value is 15 or more than 15 then 15+.

```
Table 1              Table 2

Age column.           Age column
3                       3
4                       4
15                      15+
-2                       -1
-3                       -1
100                      15+
```

Comment: Your question title makes no sense. *we have single values or 15+ values we need to have single value or 15+* doesn't even parse. It also doesn't match the body text of your post. You should [edit] to fix the title and to make it more clear what you're asking. When doing so, please remember that we don't know anything about what you're thinking or are trying to do other than the information you provide in your question.

Comment: Also - what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the CASE WHEN THEN END syntax for problems like that (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

i assume you have 3 conditions:

- negative values are always -1
- up to 14 it is the original value
- 15 and above is 15+

that means, you have to cover these 3 cases with the CASE WHEN THEN END clause. Just evaluate what comes out from your select to the first table and then transform it to the wanted outcome

Comment: We don't have upto 14 category we are having individual number like 3,4 ,21,6,78 . We have to take single values and mapped to the single value . 3 = 3 , 4=4, 21 =15+,78=15+ like this.

Comment: then the CASE WHEN works just the same way. you can add up as many cases as you want. and you can also use boolean expressions in there, so for example you can say that " > 15 = 15+" and things like that